LTSpice: Singular Matrix error. No floating nodes
I am trying to simulate the following circuit:

I get the error as displayed. Node n009 is the node just below the error dialog, connecting L2,C2, R3 and R6. I know this error can be caused by floating nodes but there are none here that I can see. Some variations of this circuit e.g. with L2 and L5 combined do work ok and run as expected so I'm puzzled why this one fails.
LTspice schematic .asc file text provided below:
Version 4
SHEET 1 1716 1284
WIRE -416 -64 -688 -64
WIRE -320 -64 -416 -64
WIRE 16 -64 -320 -64
WIRE 240 -64 16 -64
WIRE -416 -32 -416 -64
WIRE -480 16 -512 16
WIRE -688 48 -688 -64
WIRE -512 160 -512 16
WIRE -512 160 -592 160
WIRE -416 160 -416 64
WIRE 400 160 -416 160
WIRE 528 160 464 160
WIRE 800 160 528 160
WIRE -592 192 -592 160
WIRE -416 192 -416 160
WIRE 528 192 528 160
WIRE 800 192 800 160
WIRE -512 240 -512 160
WIRE -480 240 -512 240
WIRE -688 320 -688 128
WIRE -592 320 -592 272
WIRE -592 320 -688 320
WIRE -416 320 -416 288
WIRE -416 320 -592 320
WIRE 528 320 528 272
WIRE 528 320 -416 320
WIRE 800 320 800 272
WIRE 800 320 528 320
WIRE -688 336 -688 320
WIRE 16 384 16 -64
WIRE 240 384 16 384
WIRE 240 432 240 384
WIRE 192 448 128 448
WIRE -320 512 -320 -64
WIRE -512 528 -512 240
WIRE -368 528 -512 528
WIRE -368 576 -560 576
WIRE -560 608 -560 576
WIRE -320 608 -320 592
WIRE -112 608 -320 608
WIRE 128 608 128 448
WIRE 128 608 -112 608
WIRE 240 608 240 528
WIRE 704 608 240 608
WIRE 784 608 704 608
WIRE 912 608 864 608
WIRE 992 608 912 608
WIRE 1104 608 992 608
WIRE 1264 608 1184 608
WIRE 1360 608 1264 608
WIRE 1552 608 1360 608
WIRE -320 624 -320 608
WIRE 240 672 240 608
WIRE 912 672 912 608
WIRE 992 672 992 608
WIRE 704 688 704 608
WIRE 1360 688 1360 608
WIRE -560 720 -560 688
WIRE -320 720 -320 704
WIRE -320 720 -560 720
WIRE -560 752 -560 720
WIRE 128 752 128 608
WIRE 192 752 128 752
WIRE 240 784 240 768
WIRE 1264 784 1264 608
WIRE 1552 784 1552 608
WIRE 704 832 704 768
WIRE 768 832 704 832
WIRE 912 832 912 736
WIRE 992 832 992 752
WIRE 992 832 912 832
WIRE 1040 832 992 832
WIRE 1360 832 1360 768
WIRE 1424 832 1360 832
WIRE 768 848 768 832
WIRE 1040 848 1040 832
WIRE 1424 848 1424 832
WIRE 16 864 16 384
WIRE 240 864 16 864
WIRE 560 864 240 864
WIRE 704 880 704 832
WIRE 1360 880 1360 832
WIRE 240 912 240 864
WIRE 560 912 560 864
WIRE 192 928 128 928
WIRE 512 928 448 928
WIRE 992 928 992 832
WIRE 912 944 912 832
WIRE -112 1088 -112 608
WIRE 128 1088 128 928
WIRE 128 1088 -112 1088
WIRE 240 1088 240 1008
WIRE 448 1088 448 928
WIRE 448 1088 240 1088
WIRE 560 1088 560 1008
WIRE 704 1088 704 960
WIRE 704 1088 560 1088
WIRE 784 1088 704 1088
WIRE 912 1088 912 1008
WIRE 912 1088 864 1088
WIRE 992 1088 992 1008
WIRE 992 1088 912 1088
WIRE 1104 1088 992 1088
WIRE 1264 1088 1264 848
WIRE 1264 1088 1184 1088
WIRE 1360 1088 1360 960
WIRE 1360 1088 1264 1088
WIRE 1552 1088 1552 864
WIRE 1552 1088 1360 1088
WIRE 240 1152 240 1088
WIRE 560 1152 560 1088
WIRE 128 1232 128 1088
WIRE 192 1232 128 1232
WIRE 448 1232 448 1088
WIRE 512 1232 448 1232
WIRE 240 1264 240 1248
WIRE 560 1264 560 1248
FLAG -688 336 0
FLAG 240 784 0
FLAG -560 752 0
FLAG 560 1264 0
FLAG 1040 848 0
FLAG 240 1264 0
FLAG 768 848 0
FLAG 1424 848 0
SYMBOL cap 464 144 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 32µ
SYMBOL ind 512 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 202m
SYMBOL voltage -592 176 R0
WINDOW 3 -336 45 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value SINE(2.5 2.5 60)
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMBOL voltage -688 32 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL pnp -480 288 M180
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N2905A
SYMBOL npn -480 -32 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q2
SYMATTR Value BC337-25
SYMBOL res 784 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 2400
SYMBOL nmos 192 672 R0
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMATTR Value IRF640-25C
SYMBOL pmos 192 528 M180
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMATTR Value IRF9640
SYMBOL sw -320 496 R0
WINDOW 3 24 44 Left 2
SYMATTR Value ""
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMATTR SpiceModel MYSW
SYMBOL voltage -560 592 R0
WINDOW 3 -108 204 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0 99u 1u 0 100u)
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL res -336 608 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL cap 1248 784 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 32µ
SYMBOL ind 1088 624 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 109m
SYMBOL res 1536 768 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 5760
SYMBOL ind 768 624 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L3
SYMATTR Value 1m
SYMBOL cap 896 672 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL nmos 512 1152 R0
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value IRF640-25C
SYMBOL pmos 512 1008 M180
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMATTR Value IRF9640
SYMBOL ind 768 1104 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L4
SYMATTR Value 1m
SYMBOL cap 896 944 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL nmos 192 1152 R0
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMATTR Value IRF640-25C
SYMBOL pmos 192 1008 M180
SYMATTR InstName M6
SYMATTR Value IRF9640
SYMBOL ind 1088 1104 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L5
SYMATTR Value 109m
SYMBOL res 688 672 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 688 864 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 10K
SYMBOL res 1344 672 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 1000K
SYMBOL res 1344 864 R0
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 1000K
SYMBOL res 976 656 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 1000K
SYMBOL res 976 912 R0
SYMATTR InstName R9
SYMATTR Value 1000K
TEXT -240 -48 Left 2 !.tran 1
TEXT -1224 712 Left 2 !.model MYSW SW(Ron=1 Roff=1Meg Vt=0 Vh=0)
TEXT -1032 1048 Left 2 !.model IRF640-25C VDMOS (Rg=5 Vto={4.30-6m*0} Lambda=3m\n+ Rs={35m*(1+3.5m*0)} Kp={13.0/(1+8.8m*0)}\n+ Ksubthres={0.23*(1+4m*0)} Mtriode={0.35} Rd={0.1*(1+5m*0)}\n+ Cgdmax=2600p Cgdmin=10p a=0.35 Cgs=1250p Cjo=3000p \n+ m=0.75 VJ=5 IS=1n N=1.3 Rb=0.01 )


The other issue that often causes singular matrix errors is a loop of capacitors and voltage sources with no resistance. Check your circuit, including model parasitics, for those as well.

It would be quite useful for you to find n009 and label it with a net label.  This would narrow down the possibilites tremendously.

There is a trick to "smuggling" an ASC file in the question. Open it in a plain text editor (Notepad, Notepad++, etc), and copy-paste it between the XML comment delimiters <!-- and -->. That way anyone can Edit the question to extract the ASC data :)

Nice one. I linked the .asc file below but copying it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZK0t5R9f_xJFXws6Wq7VvKTMuV_VV_I/view?usp=sharing

Your circuit is failing numerically to find the DC operating point.  You can sidestep this directly by either using the startup (preferred) or uic flags for the .tran statement.  This can be done with either of these two checkboxes when editing your simulation command.


Even better would be to address the problem in the circuit itself and make it more realistic.  You haven't set an ESR (equivalent series resistance) for any of your inductors.  You should always do this when possible.  LTspice tries to preempt user oversight on this and adds 1mΩ by default, but doesn't work for all circuits.  For example, if I right-click L1 and enter in 10m for "Series Resistance", your singular matrix error is now gone.



I've taken a look at your circuit and the error you're getting. It seems like there might be a hidden floating node or a component with incorrect parameters.
Here are a few things you could try:
Double-check component values: Ensure that all resistors, capacitors, and inductors have valid values. Sometimes, even a small typo can cause issues.
Check for floating nodes: Look for any nodes that aren't connected to any other components. Even if they seem connected, there might be a hidden break in the circuit.
Try simplifying the circuit: If possible, remove unnecessary components or combine elements to see if the error persists.
Check for component mismatches: Make sure you're using the correct models for the transistors and other components.
Verify the power supply: Ensure that the power supply is set up correctly and providing the expected voltage.
If you can share the ASC file, I might be able to pinpoint the issue more easily. You could try uploading it to a file-sharing service like Google Drive or Dropbox and then sharing the link here.
Let me know if any of these suggestions help!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZK0t5R9f_xJFXws6Wq7VvKTMuV_VV_I/view?usp=sharing

Just changing the dummy load resistors to '1m' allowed it to work, although not useful as I intended them to be 1M but LTSpice seems to convert them to 1m for some reason.

@Rob190 SPICE ignores case, so it can't distinguish between M and m. To get 1 MΩ resistors, you need to enter the value as "1Meg". You can also enter "1000k" or "0.001G".

OK so I have them set to 1000K which produces the matrix error. If I set them to 1m, the simulation runs. I guess this rules out any hidden floating nodes or invalid values.
